# Не работает history api в firefox 33

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api

Когда внутри функции вызываю, то не переходит по ссылке, но выдает ошибку в firebug:
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
window.history.pushState(null, null, url);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что у тебя в переменной url находится?
Судя по тексту ошибки, предполагаю, что адрес твоего домена и адрес домена в **url** различаются, поэтому и выходит ошибка.

[Правило ограничения домена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)